# JavaFX FileChooser new file

Tags: java, file, javafx, filechooser

Is it possible to use the JavaFX File Chooser (or a similar alternative) to create new files?

Entering the name of a non-existent file works on Linux (Ubuntu to be exact) but on Windows the file chooser does not allow that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that should be possible, you just need to know the right function to call. The API for `FileChooser` details them in its opening paragraph [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html).

> A FileChooser can be used to invoke file open dialogs for selecting single file (showOpenDialog), file open dialogs for selecting multiple files (showOpenMultipleDialog) and file save dialogs (showSaveDialog).

**USAGE**

Save file:

```
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
```

Open one file:

```
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

Open multiple files:

```
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    List<File> files = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(null);
```